# Adjust canvas image size like 'background-size: cover' and responsive

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

### What I want to do

- Set `background-size:cover`-like effect on a canvas image
- Re-draw a canvas image as a window is resized (responsive)

### What I tried

I tried 2 ways below. Neither works.

1. [Simulation background-size: cover in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961839/simulation-background-size-cover-in-canvas)
2. [How to set background size cover on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403700/how-to-set-background-size-cover-on-a-canvas)

### Issue

- The image's aspect ratio is not fixed.
- I am not sure but the image does not seem to be re-rendered as a window is resized.

### My code

```js
function draw() {
  // Get <canvas>
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

  // Canvas
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const cw = canvas.width;
  const ch = canvas.height;

  // Image
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900';

  img.onload = function() {
    const iw = img.width;
    const ih = img.height;

    // 'background-size:cover'-like effect
    const aspectHeight = ih * (cw / iw);
    const heightOffset = ((aspectHeight - ch) / 2) * -1;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, heightOffset, cw, aspectHeight);
  };
}

window.addEventListener('load', draw);
window.addEventListener('resize', draw);
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  /* canvas width depends on parent/window width */
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas [width / height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) attributes do not reflect it's actual size in relation to it being sized with CSS. Given your code, `cw/ch` are fixed at `300/150`. So the whole calculation is based on incorrect values.

You need to use values that actually reflect it's visible size. Like [clientWidth / clientHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively).

A very simple solution is to update the canvas width/height attributes before using them for any calculations. E.g.:

```
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
```

Full example:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// only load the image once
const img = new Promise(r => {
  const img = new Image();

  img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900';
  img.onload = () => r(img);
});

const draw = async () => {
  // resize the canvas to match it's visible size
  canvas.width  = canvas.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

  const loaded = await img;
  const iw     = loaded.width;
  const ih     = loaded.height;
  const cw     = canvas.width;
  const ch     = canvas.height;
  const f      = Math.max(cw/iw, ch/ih);

  ctx.setTransform(
    /*     scale x */ f,
    /*      skew x */ 0,
    /*      skew y */ 0,
    /*     scale y */ f,
    /* translate x */ (cw - f * iw) / 2,
    /* translate y */ (ch - f * ih) / 2,
  );

  ctx.drawImage(loaded, 0, 0);
};

window.addEventListener('load', draw);
window.addEventListener('resize', draw);
```

```css
.--dimensions {
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
}

.--border {
    border: 3px solid #333;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#test {
    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 1rem auto 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="--dimensions --border"></canvas>
<div id="test" class="--dimensions --border"></div>
```

Comment: This code is perfect! It's very simple and short. Moreover, it is exactly the same as `background-size: cover`. Thank you for showing the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

First, load only once your image, currently you are reloading it every time the page is resized.

Then, your variables `cw` and `ch` will always be `300` and `150` since you don't set the size of your canvas. Remember, [the canvas has two different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034529/size-of-html5-canvas-via-css-versus-element-attributes?noredirect=1&lq=1), its layout one (controlled by CSS) and its buffer one (controlled by its `.width` and `.height` attributes).
You can retrieve the layout values through the element's `.offsetWidth` and `.offsetHeight` properties.

Finally, your code does a *contain* image-sizing. To do a *cover*, you can refer to the answers you linked to, and particularly to [K3N's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21961894/3702797)

```js
{
  // Get <canvas>
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  // Canvas
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // Image
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900';

  function draw() {
    // get the correct dimension as calculated by CSS
    // and set the canvas' buffer to this dimension
    const cw = canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
    const ch = canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

    if( !inp.checked ) {
      drawImageProp(ctx, img, 0, 0, cw, ch, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  img.onload = () => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', draw);
    draw();
  };

  inp.oninput = draw;
}

// by Ken Fyrstenberg https://stackoverflow.com/a/21961894/3702797
function drawImageProp(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetX, offsetY) {

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        x = y = 0;
        w = ctx.canvas.width;
        h = ctx.canvas.height;
    }

    // default offset is center
    offsetX = typeof offsetX === "number" ? offsetX : 0.5;
    offsetY = typeof offsetY === "number" ? offsetY : 0.5;

    // keep bounds [0.0, 1.0]
    if (offsetX < 0) offsetX = 0;
    if (offsetY < 0) offsetY = 0;
    if (offsetX > 1) offsetX = 1;
    if (offsetY > 1) offsetY = 1;

    var iw = img.width,
        ih = img.height,
        r = Math.min(w / iw, h / ih),
        nw = iw * r,   // new prop. width
        nh = ih * r,   // new prop. height
        cx, cy, cw, ch, ar = 1;

    // decide which gap to fill    
    if (nw < w) ar = w / nw;                             
    if (Math.abs(ar - 1) < 1e-14 && nh < h) ar = h / nh;  // updated
    nw *= ar;
    nh *= ar;

    // calc source rectangle
    cw = iw / (nw / w);
    ch = ih / (nh / h);

    cx = (iw - cw) * offsetX;
    cy = (ih - ch) * offsetY;

    // make sure source rectangle is valid
    if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
    if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
    if (cw > iw) cw = iw;
    if (ch > ih) ch = ih;

    // fill image in dest. rectangle
    ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy, cw, ch,  x, y, w, h);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  /* canvas width depends on parent/window width */
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<label><input id="inp" type="checkbox">show CSS rendering</label>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. It's very easy to understand. Now thanks to you, I understand why my code didn't work.